# Error while using python to run a macro from one workbook to another workbook

Tags: python, excel, vba

I store my excel macros in a specific file called "Macro.xlsm" in the following path `"C:\Users\example\OneDrive\Desktop\example"`. This macro will be used in other workbooks.

I have a code below:

```
def write_pdf_data_to_excel(pdf_text, excel_file_path):

    # Load Excel workbook
    wb = load_workbook(excel_file_path)
    ws = wb.active

    # Find the first empty row in column E
    row = 1
    while ws[f'E{row}'].value is not None:
        row += 1

    # Write PDF data to Excel starting from the first empty row
    for line in pdf_text.split('\n'):
        ws[f'E{row}'] = line
        row += 1

    # Save changes to Excel file
    wb.save(excel_file_path)
    print("PDF data written to Excel.")

    # Open Excel workbook containing macro
    macro_excel_path = r"C:\Users\example\OneDrive\Desktop\example\Macro.xlsm"
    macro_app = xw.App(visible=False)
    macro_wb = macro_app.books.open(macro_excel_path)
    print("Macro Workbook opened.")
    
    # Select the range of newly pasted cells
    macro_sheet = macro_wb.sheets[0]
    last_row = row - 1
    range_to_select = macro_sheet.range(f'E{last_row}:E{last_row}')
    range_to_select.select()
    print("Range selected.")

    # Run macro
    macro_sheet.api.Application.Run("SelectionTextToColumn")  # Replace "SelectionTextToColumn" with the name of your macro

    macro_wb.close()
    macro_app.quit()
    print("Macro execution completed.")
```

There were other codes which were running fine prior to this code.
The code can be executed until `print("Range selected.")`
The error code returned is `com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146788248), None)`
Can anyone guide me please?

Comment: Add `print(last_row)` before `range_to_select.select()` to validate the row# is a positive number.